# How do you store content or metadata within a css keyframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, css-animations

Does anyone know why I can't see the effects of the content property in my keyframe animation?
I tried something like

```
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    0.000% {-webkit-transform: matrix(1,0,0,1,294,-135);
                     color:blue;
                     content:"test";
           }
    /*... more keyframes that changed the -webkit-transform property...*/
}
```

When I was watching my animated HTML `div` during the animation, I could see the effects of the `-webkit-transform` and `color` properties, but not the `content` property. It's as if the `content` property wasn't even applied during the animation. jQuery didn't return a value either when I did `$(<my animated html element>).css("content");` However, repeatedly testing `$(<my animated html element>).css("-webkit-transform")` returned different values as the `div` moved across the screen.

I don't necessarily want to use the `content` property to display anything. I want to be able to store some meta data in the CSS `keyframe` rule so that I can refer back to the corresponding percentage at which the animation is at. I need to be able to run an animation on an infinite loop, and periodically query the animated HTML element to figure out how far along it is in the animation. I thought that I could use the `content` property to just put arbitrary strings, but it's not working on Chrome or Firefox. Does anyone have any ideas how I'd store metadata within the `keyframe` CSS rule?

Comment: I don't think you can use `content` this way. If I am not wrong, it was originally designed for the `:after` and `:before` elements. [MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content)

Comment: I agree, but I think it's strange that I can go into the Chrome developer tools, select an html element and manually set its css content property. Then, I'm able to use jQuery's .css("content") to retrieve the string that I just set.

Answer (score 0):

I dont fully understand what you are trying to say when you are storing the metadata in keyframe.. In anyway, jquery or the javascript cannot read the css3 'content' data. Also I am pretty sure you cannot use content property inside the keyframe. you either need to use :after or :before. eg.

```
#box:before {
    content: "test";
}
```

If you want the animation run infinte, you can use

```
-webkit-animation: mymove 5s infinite;
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: My main problem is I have no idea how to get what keyframe is being played; I need to find what percentage the animation is currently at. So, I thought that I might set a css property, like content, to equal the current keyframe percent. Then I could use jQuery's .css("content") method to get the percentage of the current keyframe. Now, I can set the z-index in the keyframe rule, and when I periodically query .css('z-index'), I get the percentage that the animation is currently at. But I might want to also animate the z-index, so I need to set something else. I thought content would work.

Comment: I am pretty sure you cannot pass the animation percentage from css to javascipt easily. You need to run a timer to perodically to check the position or transformation of the element and this is not easy. I recomend to check this very good article on css animation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj680076(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check this url `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj680076(v=vs.85).aspx`.
This article works good on Internet Explore 9+
For another browsers other than IE 9+, you need to copy and paste the css3 animation keyframe with vendor specific keywork.

for eg. for chrome you have to write the css in the article as:

```
@keyframes fadeOut {
    from {  
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

.TransformDemoDivFadeOut:hover {
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-name: fadeOut;
    @-webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    @-webkit-animation-name: fadeOut;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
    from {  
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```